# 1inch swap contract error (callBytes failed)

Tags: polygon

I'm currently doing some tests using 1inch smart contract in order to be able to swap currency to another.

But I'm facing multiple errors that I didn't understand.

Scenario (on Polygon):

- Call [https://api.1inch.exchange/v3.0/137/swap](https://docs.1inch.io/api/quote-swap#swap) to get the transaction data
- Use the result to send it to Polygon (using Web3 & Infura)
- Facing the error in polygonscan (contract execution revert)

That is the list of the different error I facing :

```
callBytes failed: Error(External call failed: Error(BAL#508))
callBytes failed: Error(External call failed: Error(External call failed: Error(Deadline not met)))
callBytes failed: Error(External call failed: Error(External call failed: Error(LOP: taking > remaining)))
callBytes failed: Error(External call failed: Error(External call failed: Error(timeout)))
callBytes failed: Error(External call failed: Error(LOP: predicate returned false))
```

Every error is related to callBytes.

**My investigation:**
The contract I call is this one : [0x11111112542d85b3ef69ae05771c2dccff4faa26](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x11111112542d85b3ef69ae05771c2dccff4faa26).
This contract call the method `callBytes` from this contract : [0x11431a89893025d2a48dca4eddc396f8c8117187](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x11431a89893025d2a48dca4eddc396f8c8117187) but this one isn't verified and I didn't find any documentation...

If anyone has an idea of what these errors mean it would be a great help to me.

Thanks.

Exemple transaction :

BAL#508 : [0xf2c219d6f42ac3f47c1bb9212af26512aa6d574a80d0bff982bacf808d2d5446](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xf2c219d6f42ac3f47c1bb9212af26512aa6d574a80d0bff982bacf808d2d5446)

Deadline not met :
[0x98e8c5b45391ec7ae4f4ce5e452500d0a25378385b4b0ea342858a38a5cfc7f7](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x98e8c5b45391ec7ae4f4ce5e452500d0a25378385b4b0ea342858a38a5cfc7f7)

LOP: predicate returned false : [0x77470ea196cf0dde29e6582981e30dfdcd098109bdb039ab1cadf5144d066e8f](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x77470ea196cf0dde29e6582981e30dfdcd098109bdb039ab1cadf5144d066e8f)

LOP: taking > remaining : [0x2563267b3cee277fc6a57e063c7706c054411bb307f987c5df6f297798153917](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x2563267b3cee277fc6a57e063c7706c054411bb307f987c5df6f297798153917)

Timeout : [0x395e96eb144e2fd6cd4bbbff693a8658afb83e0fcaac81f5f6e4dc32c7b55a77](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x395e96eb144e2fd6cd4bbbff693a8658afb83e0fcaac81f5f6e4dc32c7b55a77)

Not that the error is not the same on polygonscan, for getting the error I use npm package eth-revert-reason

Comment: Do you have a failed transaction hash?

Comment: For sure, I've add this in the main post

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because the `callBytes` you passed isn't properly parsed by the function you are calling.  One way this error happens is if you call the swap function in `AggregationRouterV3` contract. So instead of calling the swap call the `address(0x11111112542d85b3ef69ae05771c2dccff4faa26).call({'data':...data from swap api call)`